# jQuery Mobile site goes blank on desktop after back button is pressed

Tags: jquery-mobile, background

I have a jQuery mobile app that is working perfectly in mobile, however I need to make it work on desktop as well. This is no big deal, however a strange anomaly is happening. Randomly, when the back button is pressed, the screen will turn the same color as the background of the body element, hiding any content. Has anyone else experienced this or does anyone have any thoughts as to why this is occurring?

Comment: Can we access your desktop application? Without it this question is pretty much dead end.

Comment: Yeah that's the problem. Unfortunately this isn't possible at the moment. I was just more looking for opinions or if anyone has experienced this themselves. If not it's okay. I can just close the question.

Comment: My advice, close it and open it again at Monday, jQuery Mobile tag is a ghost town over weekend.